# HTML Object Tag

Tags: web, content-security-policy

In a recent PT assignment, I overcame that a CSP policy where the `object-src` be set to `self`. When validated against Google CSP Evaluator, it reported that it the `object-src` can be set to `none` instead of `self`.

Would like to ask for scenarios where the `object-src` tag can be abused when it is set to `self`, as I am unable to think of any possible scenario where this can be abused when a user is unable to interact with the website (no places to login, or specify any inputs).

And hence, in this case it is safe to for the `object-src` tag to remain as `self` and not `none`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certainly a matter of principle of least privilege. You can't think of a scenario where it matters. I don't know enough to know if there's a plausible one, and all the generic ones I can think of are indeed implausible (e.g. there exists a page on the relevant domain, which has inadequate CSP, and that tries to parse its parent window's domain and can be XSSed if it does so?). Nonetheless, if there's no need for the page to use the object tag at all, then it should indeed specify `object-src none`. That should be the default for all security rules: deny everything that is not justifiably required, and allow only the smallest windows around things you must allow at all.

So, is it safe? Impossible to say without knowing more, but the odds are good. Is it a best practice? No. Deny any and all access - even to sourcing things from your own domain - that the page doesn't actually need.